# Set cookie with apex and read it with javascript

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, cookies

I need to set a cookie in an apex controller and then read it in a the helper of a lightning component.

Comment: This sounds like an x-y problem. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: You can't read or write cookies in Lightning-Apex interactions. As David said, you'll need an alternative solution. Please read about the [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) for more information.